# Selecting dates that are between the previous 12 to 9 month range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I need help selecting dates that are between the previous 12 to 9 month range.  As an example if today is 2-22-2017 I need to pull a date range from 2-1-2016 to 3-31-2016.

I can select all dates from the previous 12 months using this:

```
WHERE READDATE >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,-12,GETDATE())), 0)
AND READDATE <= DATEADD(s,-12,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

But I can't figure out how to exclude dates after the previous 9 months giving me that 3 months window.

Comment: What version of SQL Server please?

Comment: 2-1-2016 to 3-31-2016 is a 2 months window, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
...
WHERE 
    -- >= 2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
    READDATE >= DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)
    -- < 2016-04-01 00:00:00.000
    READDATE < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()) - 10, 0) 
...
```

Please note that with dates it is usually best to compare it this way:

```
X >= lower bound
    AND
X < upper bound
```

This is why I change `<= '20160331'` to `< '20160401'`. While it works fine with your sample using what seems to be DATE types, it may give incorrect results using dates with a TIME part.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later then you can use `DATEFROMPARTS` to help:

```
WHERE READDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1))
  AND READDATE <  DATEADD(MONTH, -9,DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),MONTH(GETDATE()),1))
```

Minor modifications will make this work for calendar quarters too instead if rolling three month periods.

Before 2012 `DATEFROMPARTS` did not exist though for this case there is an easy hack with string casting:

```
WHERE READDATE >= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(7),GETDATE(),121) AS DATE))
  AND READDATE <  DATEADD(MONTH, -9,CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(7),GETDATE(),121) AS DATE))
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you prefer MM over just typing out what you mean (MONTH)? [Shorthand is a dangerous habit with almost zero upside](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: an age-old habit that I occasionally fall back into (despite nagging others not to do it)!

Comment: Unfortunately not using 2012

Comment: @user19300 So what version are you using? SQL Server 2008, at least, I hope?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wary about using `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` clause due to potential impact on estimates:

- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : DATEDIFF](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug)
- [Performance Surprises and Assumptions : DATEADD](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-performance/surprises-dateadd)

Also, if you care about performance, I've proven that using things like `FORMAT()` or `CAST/CONVERT()` to a string in order to strip time from a `datetime` is sub-optimal:

- [What is the most efficient way to trim time from datetime?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime)
- [Trimming time from datetime – a follow-up](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/trim-time)
- [FORMAT() is nice and all, but...](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

And since you are not on SQL Server 2012 or greater, you can't use `DATEFROMPARTS()`, which is probably the cleanest way to do that. But there is still a tidy way to get the beginning of the current month (first, subtract days from today, then convert to `date`), and from there it's trivial to subtract a year, and then 9 months, and build a proper `WHERE` clause:

```
DECLARE @ThisMonth date = DATEADD(DAY, 1-DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE());

SELECT ... FROM dbo.tablename ...
  WHERE READDATE >= DATEADD(YEAR,  -1, @ThisMonth)
    AND READDATE <  DATEADD(MONTH, -9, @ThisMonth);
```

I wouldn't ever use `>=` and `<=` for a date range query. This is equivalent to `BETWEEN`, and [can lead to all kinds of inaccuracies](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), like trusting that data could only be recorded up to 12 seconds before midnight (?). Don't try to find data *at or before* the "end" of a period - the way you want to think about this is that you just want everything *before* the beginning of the *next* period.

Some other reading on date/range queries:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations)
- [#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly)

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution, it'll give you all dates between the selected range.

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
    ,@enddate DATETIME

SET @startdate = '1/1/2012'
SET @enddate = '1/15/2012'

;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT @startdate DateVal

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateVal + 1
    FROM cte
    WHERE DateVal + 1 <= @enddate
    )
SELECT c.DateVal, COALESCE(sum(quantity),0)
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN YourTable t ON c.DateVal = t.ProductionDate
GROUP BY c.DateVal
```